# what is the difference between hadoop.tmp.dir and mapred.temp.dir and mapreduce.cluster.temp.dir

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I want to know what is a difference between `hadoop.tmp.dir` and `mapred.temp.dir`  also how `mapred.temp.dir` [deprecated] differs from `mapreduce.cluster.temp.dir`

Answer (score 0):

`hadoop.tmp.dir` is the highest-level temporary directory.  It defaults to `/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}`.

By default, `mapred.temp.dir` refers to a directory *under* `hadoop.tmp.dir`:   `${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/temp`.

Logically, this makes sense because MapReduce (like Hive, Spark, etc) is a subset of Hadoop, so it should be stored under Hadoop's temp directory.

Comment: thanks for answering, please suggest me about `mapreduce.cluster.temp.dir`

Comment: I'd suggest the documentation: `mapreduce.cluster.temp.dir` defaults to `${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/temp`

Comment: I mean, I wanted to know why `cluster` was added in the new property and `mapred.temp.dir` is deprecated? Is it related to cluster level temp directory?